# Scikit-Learn accuracy score does not show accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda, kaggle

I'm a beginner in Machine Learning and I'm learning through the Kaggle competitions.  I've started off with the Titanic competition and now I'm trying to measure the accuracy of my prediction with the scikit-learn `accuracy_score` function but the output does not really make sense.  Here is the output I am getting:

```
[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]

<function accuracy_score at 0x000001AA46EFBD90>
```

And here is my code:

```
*imports have been omitted to avoid crowding

    train_path = "C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\Titanic Data\\train.csv"
    train_data = pd.read_csv(train_path)

    train_data['Sex'] = pd.factorize(train_data.Sex)[0]

    columns_of_interest = ['Survived','Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age']
    filtered_titanic_data = train_data.dropna(axis=0)

    x = filtered_titanic_data[columns_of_interest]
    y = filtered_titanic_data.Survived

    train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

    titanic_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    titanic_model.fit(train_x, train_y)

    val_predictions = titanic_model.predict(val_x)
    accuracy_score(val_y, val_predictions)

    print(val_predictions)
    print(accuracy_score)
```

Comment: You are printing the function `accuracy_score` and not what the function returns, thats why you see `<function accuracy_score at 0x000001AA46EFBD90>`. Save the value of `accuracy_score(val_y, val_predictions)` into a variable and print that variable.

Comment: "I'm a beginner in Machine Learning" ... This question seems to demonstrate that you are a beginner at programming in general.  Perhaps a short python course would help?  I learned with [Google's python course](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) years ago.  It's a bit fast paced and terse, however, but there are a [huge number of others out there](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers)

Comment: @Scott if a simple mistake made someone a beginner, then there are no senior developers.  I'm an Android developer, mate.  Settle down.

Comment: @OnurOzbek, not trying to have a measuring contest, just noting that you're jumping into the deep end of the python pool. [Google's python course](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) is right up your alley then, since it is geared toward those who already have some knowledge of programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to print the results of the `accuracy_score(val_y, val_predictions)` line.

e.g. `print(accuracy_score(val_y, val_predictions))`

Comment: Now I have an accuracy of 1.0.  Is that normal?  Seems too good to be true.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure what's in your `.csv` file.  `print(val_predictions); print(val_y)` and compare for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Either annotate accuracy_score in a variable
acc= accuracy_score(predictions,val_y)
print (acc)
Or print the accuracy_score
print accuracy_score(predictions,val_y)